# The Stupid Assembly and Temp ASP.NET files story

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, windows-server-2003, .net-assembly

> really sorry for reposting before i posted some confidentional
> information by mistake

I am getting this exception, it started out of nowhere, I've got no idea why it's mis matching assemblies, I've had this error before for another assembly and solved it by deleting asp.net temp files but that was a different DLL.

Why is it loading the DLL from asp.net temp files when THE STUPID DLL is in GAC and web application's bin folder?

> The operation failed. Bind result: hr = 0x80131040. No description
> available.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from:
> c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll Running
> under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
> --- A detailed error log follows.

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = domainName\userName

LOG: DisplayName = some.DLLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)

LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/somefolder/Applications/somefolder/

LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\somefolder\Applications\somefolder\bin

LOG: Dynamic Base = c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\some folder\dfgdfgdf

LOG: Cache Base = c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\some folder\dfgdfgdf

LOG: AppName = 34tert4t4
Calling assembly : somelibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
```

**Detailed Error by Fusion log**

> WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: PUBLIC KEY
>
> TOKEN ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly
>
> definition found. ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80131040. ERR: Failed
>
> to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Temp` folder is used for [assembly shadow copying](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx) as described [here](http://www.ipreferjim.com/2012/04/asp-net-appdomains-and-shadow-copying/). It is basically to avoid locking the assemblies and allow their in-place update.